# Are there any languages that have a do-until loop?

Tags: loops, language-features, do-loops

Is there any programming language that has a do-until loop?

Example:

```
do
{
    <statements>
}
until (<condition>);
```

which is basically equivalent to:

```
do
{
    <statements>
}
while (<negated condition>);
```

NOTE: I'm looking for post-test loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby has until.

```
i=0
begin
  puts i
  i += 1
end until i==5
```

Comment: This is a different construct entirely though, because it won't run once initially regardless of the while/until condition, as do-while loops do.

Comment: @Jake Petroules Yep, you are correct. I modified it so it will run once regardless of conditional.

Comment: So Ruby has both `while` and `until` forms too, interesting. I wonder why more languages didn't do this.

Comment: Pascal has repeat-until, so that means Delphi does too.

Comment: @Jake - I imagine the reason more languages don't have it is that there are an (almost?) unlimited number of different control structures that can be used. A language designer needs to choose the ones they want to include in their language to balance complexity/size against convenience.

Answer (score 1):

VBA!

[Do-Until-Loop](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Language-Basics/DoLoopUntil.htm)

[Do-Loop-Until](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/do-until-loop.htm)

Although I think quite a number of people here would doubt if it is a real language at all, but well, BASIC is how Microsoft started (quite weak argument for many, I know)...

Comment: Interesting, it looks like VBA has both do-while AND do-until. That's a nice flexibility.

Comment: @Jake Yes it is http://www.anthony-vba.kefra.com/vba/vbabasic3.htm#Do_..._Loop_Until . VBA can be nice and handy at times :)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in VB.Net

```
bExitFromLoop = False 
Do  
    'Executes the following Statement  
Loop Until bExitFromLoop
```

It is also possible in SDF-P on BS2000 (Fujitsu/Siemens Operating System)

```
/ DECLARE-VARIABLE A
/ DECLARE-VARIABLE SWITCH-1(TYPE=*BOOLEAN)
/ SET-VARIABLE A = 5
/ SET-VARIABLE SWITCH-1 = ON
/ REPEAT
/   A = A + 10
/   IF (A > 50)
/      SET-VARIABLE SWITCH-1 = OFF
/   END-IF
/ UNTIL (SWITCH-1 = OFF)
/ SHOW-VARIABLE A
A = 55
```

Is is also possible is C or C++ using a macro that define `until`

Example (definition):

```
#define until(cond) while(!(##cond))
```

Example (utilisation):

```
int i = 0;
do  {
    cout << i << "\n";
    i++;
    } until(i == 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB we can find something like:

```
 Reponse = InputBox("Please Enter Pwd")
  Do Until Reponse = "Bob-pwr148" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Eiffel offers you an until loop.

```
from 
  x := 1 
until 
  x > 100 
loop 
  ... 
end
```

There is also an "across" loop as well. Both are very powerful and expressive.

The design of this loop has more to offer. There are two more parts to its grammar that will help us resolve two important "correctness" problems.

1. Endless loop protection.
2. Iteration failure detection.

**Endless Loop Protection**

Let's modify our loop code a little by adding a *loop variant*.

```
from 
  x := 1
  v := 1_000
until 
  x > 100 
variant
  v
loop 
  ...
  v := v - 1 
end
```

The loop variant is (essentially) a count-down variable, but not just any old variable. By using the *variant* keyword, we are telling the compiler to pay attention to **v**. Specifically, the compiler is going to generate code that watchdogs the **v** variable for two conditions:

1. Does **v** decrease with each iteration of the loop (are we counting down). It does no good to try and use a count-down variable if it is (in fact) **not** counting down, right? If the loop variant is not counting down (decreasing by any amount), then we throw an exception.
2. Does **v** ever reach a condition of less than zero? If so, then we throw an exception.

Both of these work together through the compiler and variant variable to detect when and if our iterating loop fails to iterate or iterates too many times.

In the example above, our code is communicating to us a story that it expects to iterate zero to 1_000 times, but not more. If it is more, then we stop the loop, which leaves us to wonder: Do we really have cases were we iterate more than 1_000 times, or is there something wrong that our condition is failing to become *True*?

**Loop Invariant**

Now that we know what a **loop variant** is, we need to understand what a **loop invariant** is.

The invariant is a set of one or more Boolean conditions that must hold *True* after each iteration through the *loop*. Why do we want these?

Imagine you have 1_000_000 iterations and one of them fails. You don't have time to walk through each iteration, examining it to see it is okay or not. So, you create a set of one or more conditions that are tested upon completion of each iteration. If the one or all of the conditions fail, then you know precisely which iteration (and its deterministic state) is causing the problem!

The **loop invariant** might look something like:

```
from 
  x := 1
  y := 0
  v := 1_000
invariant
  y = x - 1
until 
  x > 100 
variant
  v
loop 
  ...
  x := x + 1
  y := y + 1
  v := v - 1 
end
```

In the example above, y is trailing x by 1. We expect that after each iteration, y will always be x - 1. So, we create a **loop invariant** using the **invariant** keyword that states our Boolean assertion. If y fails to be x - 1, the loop will immediately throw an exception and let us know precisely which iteration has failed to keep the assertion *True*.

**CONCLUSION**

Our loop is now quite tight and secure—well guarded against failure (bugs, errors).